# Recursion with pointers -C

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, tree

I wrote a method that is supposed to use recursion to grow a 'snowflake', which is essentially a tree.  For some reason while debugging, it only adds one row to the tree and will not go further than that.  I am thinking it has something to do with pointers but can't seem to figure it out what is wrong with it.  Help would be very appreciated.

```
int growth(Snowflake * root, Snowflake * parent, Ray * ray){
    printf("*\n");
    printf("%f\n", root->ray->starting_point);
    printf("%f\n", ray->angle);
    if (root->middle != NULL){
        printf("Found middle! \n");
        growth(root->middle, root, ray);
    }
    else if (root->right != NULL){
        printf("Found off center!\n");
        growth(root->right, root, ray);
        printf("Found off middle!\n");
        growth(root->left, root, ray);
    }
    else{
        if (parent == NULL){
            printf("MY PARENTS ARE DEAD!\n");
            parent = root;
            //root = &parent;
        }
        printf("Starting Again!\n");
        Snowflake * add = malloc(sizeof(Snowflake));
        add->parent = parent;
        add->middle = NULL;
        add->right = NULL;
        add->left = NULL;
        add->ray = ray;
        add->ray->starting_point = add->parent->ray->end_point;
        add->ray->end_point = add->ray->starting_point + 1;
        printf("%f\n",add->ray->starting_point);
        printf("%f\n",add->ray->end_point);
        if (add->ray->angle == 0){
            add->parent->middle = add;
        }
        else{
            add->parent->right = add;
            add->parent->left = add;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Please indent your code and also provide the definition of `Snowflake` and `Ray` type.

Comment: @Dutt, have you tried to read the first two sentences of OP...?

Comment: If program behaves differently under the debugger and run standalone, it's often caused by uninitialized variable - DEBUG version may allocate variables in slightly different manner. Additionally, memory allocator may fill de-allocated blocks with some pattern in debug version, so if you use a pointer to freed memory you may get different behaviour of release and debug version of application.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following issues with your code:

1. I don't see any checks to make sure that `root != NULL`.
2. I don't know whether you are using the return value from the function. There are three recursive calls to the function none of which return. I think,

   ```
   growth(root->middle, root, ray);
   ```

   should be replaced by

   ```
   return growth(root->middle, root, ray);
   ```
3. In this block,

   ```
   else if (root->right != NULL){
       printf("Found off center!\n");
       growth(root->right, root, ray);
       printf("Found off middle!\n");
       growth(root->left, root, ray);
   }
   ```

   you are not checking whether `root->left` is `NULL`. Perhaps you meant to use:

   ```
   else if (root->right != NULL){
       printf("Found off center!\n");
       growth(root->right, root, ray);
   }
   else if (root->left != NULL){
       printf("Found off middle!\n");
       growth(root->left, root, ray);
   }
   ```

   If you meant to use the second block of code, I would add couple of `return` statements and change it to:

   ```
   else if (root->right != NULL){
       printf("Found off center!\n");
       return growth(root->right, root, ray);
   }
   else if (root->left != NULL){
       printf("Found off middle!\n");
       return growth(root->left, root, ray);
   }
   ```
4. This block of code

   ```
     if (parent == NULL){
         printf("MY PARENTS ARE DEAD!\n");
         parent = root;
         //root = &parent;
     }
   ```

   is going to be problematic if `root == NULL`. I don't know how you can ascertain that that does not happen.

Hope this helps.